# Paypal connection fails in PHP (Dockerized website)

Tags: php, docker, paypal

In my php website the page redirection associated with paypal is not working by giving the following in the apache error log. I have exposed port 80 as well as 443 in Dockerfile. Rest of the things are working fine in the site and the site with the same code is running fine in my local apache server.

```
*   Trying 173.0.82.83...
* Connected to api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com (173.0.82.83) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: 
ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / AES256-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Jose; O=PayPal, Inc.; OU=PayPal 
Production; CN=api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
*        start date: Jan 14 00:00:00 2016 GMT
*        expire date: Jan 14 23:59:59 2018 GMT
*        subjectAltName: api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com matched
*        issuer: C=US; O=Symantec Corporation; OU=Symantec Trust Network; 
CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /nvp HTTP/1.1
Host: api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 655
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 655 out of 655 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 04 Sep 2017 08:07:48 GMT
< Server: Apache
< X-SLR-RETRY-API: SetExpressCheckout
< X-PAYPAL-OPERATION-NAME: SetExpressCheckout
< X-PAYPAL-API-RC: 
< Connection: close
< HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR: sandbox.slc
< Paypal-Debug-Id: 6692e8ec22b4a
< Set-Cookie: X-PP SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.API.1%26silo_version%3D1880%26app%3Dappdispatcher_apit%26TIME%3D3691621721%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3Dsandbox.slc; Expires=Mon, 04 Sep 2017 08:37:56 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
< Content-Length: 137
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

Please help me in fixing this error.

I can find error logs under apache in my local and in case of success scenarios nothing is being logged

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 installed in oracle VM. I am not able to ping paypal sandbox URL from my server in VM. If I am trying to ping the URL from my local commandprompt, I am getting Request Timed out inspite of successful paypal connection in my local apache (from XAMP).

Comment: Post the logs from local, when it works

Comment: We are logging errors alone.